# Critical exponent in mean field theory

Tags: phase-transition, quantum-statistics

In the book I'm recently reading about quantum statistics, the author takes the following example to show how to obtain critical exponent:

Considering magnetic system in a simple case where both magnetic polarization and external magnetic field are uniform over space, then the free energy is:

$$\psi(m,h) = -m h + \frac{1}{2} r_0 m^2 + \mu_0 m^4$$

where $r_0 = a_0t$ and $ \mu_0 > 0$. $a_0$ is a constant coefficient and $t = (T - T_c)/T_c$, ${T_{c}}$ is the Curie temperature.

So the energy is
$$E[m,h]=\int d^{d}x \psi(m,h) \, .$$

Therefore the partition function is

$$Z=\int(Dm)e^{-\frac{E[m,h]}{k_{B}T}}$$
where $k_{B}$ is Boltzmann constant
In a rough approximation, $Z$ can be replaced by the term contributing most, hence we have
$$\frac{\partial \psi(m,h)}{\partial m}|_{m_{0}}=0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial^{2} \psi(m,h)}{\partial^{2} m}|_{m_{0}}>0 \, .$$

After skipping some process, we find the specific heat:
$$
C =
\begin{cases}
0 \quad \text{for} \quad t < 0 \\
\frac{3 a_0^2 T}{8\mu_0 T_c^2} \quad \text{for} \quad t>0
\end{cases}
$$
Then the author says to reflect the discontinuity of $C$ at temperature $T_{c}$, $\alpha$ must be zero with $C\sim (T_c - T)^{-\alpha}$.

So here is my question:

why $\alpha=0$? To me, it seems more sensible to set $\alpha=-1$ because $C$ is propotional to $T$.

Comment: Because setting $\alpha=-1$ would mean that $C$ vanishes linearly with $T$ as $T$ decreases toward $T_c$, which is not the case ($C$ is proportional to $T$, not to $T-T_c$ when $T>T_c$).

Comment: Note also that the proper interpretation of these critical exponents is as follows: we say that $X\sim |T-T_c|^\gamma$ if $\lim_{T\to T_c} \log X/\log|T-T_c| = \gamma$ (if the exponent depends on whether you approach $T_c$ from above, resp. below, then you have to consider the right, resp. left, limit). In your case, you have $-\alpha = \lim_{T\downarrow T_c} (c+\log T)/\log|T-T_c| = 0$.